# Finding the $k^{\rm th} $ derivative.

Tags: derivatives

Derive an expression for the $k^{(th)}$ derivative of the following:

$$(a)\quad f(x) = \frac {1}{(x-a)^n},\ a\in \Bbb R,\ n\in \Bbb N$$
$$(b)\quad f(x) = \frac {1}{x^2-1} $$
$$(c)\quad f(x) = \frac {e^{2x}}{(x-a)^2}$$

This is a first year college math question. I've thought about using the general Leibniz rule but it seems too simple a solution, also I'm not sure how to break up the expression for Leibniz rule. Suggested solutions are appreciated, detailed solutions would be godsent...

Comment: is it a formula for the kth derivative or the derivative at a point?

Comment: For the second, you may want to consider using the identity $\frac{1}{x^2-1} = \frac{0.5}{x-1} - \frac{0.5}{x+1}$.  Coming up with a general expression for the third looks like a pain, though, if you haven't been introduced to Taylor expansions yet.

Comment: @user361424 wont that just give you a value for the derivative at 0? If OP is looking for a formula that won't help

Comment: @qbert, why would that only give a value for the derivative at 0?  Once you've got those two values, you come up with formulae for the derivatives of each, which shouldn't be hard (I don't want to completely do a frosh's homework for them...).

Comment: @qbert The solution should be for the kth derivative. For example if k = 0, then that would just be f(x), if k = 1 that would be the first derivative, and so on. And I don't expect you to do the homework for me, just suggestions  on how to approach would help.

Comment: @user361424 because taylor's theorem gives you the derivative of the function at the point you expanded around?

Comment: @chris24 the only way I see to do this is find a pattern or use liebniz

Comment: @qbert, Taylor series give you an expression for many functions, $e^{2x}$ certainly being among them, valid on the entire real number line.  This expansion can be used to get expressions easier to get the kth derivative of.  But yeah, if the general Leibniz rule was taught to you recently, I expect it's what your professor wants.

Comment: @user361424 yes, obviously taylor's does give you a valid expression for the function. How do you propose to use that expression to find the value of the k'th derivative?

Comment: @user361424 Just to confirm a solution involving the general Leibniz rule for say part (c) would look like this:

$$\sum_{r=0}^k\ ^kC_r\ (e^{2x})^{(k-r)}\ ((x-a)^{-2})^{(r)}$$

Is there anything else to be done or would that be a sufficient solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Do the first ones, and deduce (and eventually prove by induction) the general case, for example

$$f(x)=\frac1{(x-a)^n}\implies\begin{cases}f'(x)=-\cfrac n{(x-a)^{n+1}}\\{}\\
f''(x)=\cfrac{n(n+1)}{(x-a)^{n+2}}\\{}\\
f'''(x)=-\cfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{(x-a)^{n+3}}\\{}\\\ldots\ldots\end{cases}$$

or

$$f(x)=\frac1{x^2-1}=\frac12\left(\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}\right)\implies\begin{cases}f'(x)=\cfrac12\left(-\cfrac1{(x-1)^2}+\cfrac1{(x+1)^2}\right)\\{}\\
f''(x)=\cfrac12\left(\cfrac2{(x-1)^3}-\cfrac2{(x+1)^3}\right)\\{}\\\ldots\ldots\end{cases}$$

and etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, much appreciated.